# How to integrate $x^2/{\sqrt{16-x^2}}$ using trig substitution

Tags: integration

I try first by substituting x for 4sin(u), but then i get stuck and im not sure what to do, thanks.

Comment: $x = 4\sin u$, which means $dx = 4 \cos u du$.

Comment: You will end up wanting to integrate a constant times $\sin^2 t$. One usual way to do it is to use $\cos 2t=1-2\sin^2 t$.

Answer (score 0):

After substituting $x=4 \sin u$, you'll have $dx = 4 \cos u du$, and the whole expression can then be rewritten as follows:
$$ \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{16-x^2}} dx =   \frac{16 \sin^2 u}{\sqrt{16(1 - \sin^2 u)}} 4 \cos u du$$

Now use the identity $1-\sin^2u = \cos^2 u$, simplify the denominator, and reduce everything in sight.  Now you're ready to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Try substitution $x=4\sin{u}$. Then 
$$\int\frac{x^2dx}{\sqrt{16-x^2}}=\int\frac{16\sin^2{u}\cos{u}du}{4\cos{u}}=4\int\sin^2{u}du$$

Use $\cos{2u}=1-2\sin^2{u}$ in the last step and integrate.

You can also try with $x=4\cos{u}$